# get a number from txt add 1 and write it back in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The titles says everything, I have a txt file called `totalcred.txt` with a number, all I want to do is:

1. keep the number written on the `.txt` file in a variable
2. add +195 to this variable
3. replace the old number with the newer (the one who got +195)

But nothing on this earth worked until now, I got dissapointed.

Here's my code so for (I tried lot of things too):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (totalcred.txt) DO (
    set val=%%a
    IF [%val%] GEQ [0] (
        set /a val += 195
        echo %val% > totalcred.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Main problem in your code: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you are writing *and* reading a variable within the same block of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a IN (totalcred.txt) DO (

set /a val=%%a+0


goto con

)

:con
set /a val2=%val%+100
echo %val2%

(Echo(%val2%)>totalcred.txt
```

Comment: Please also include some narrative along with your code to describe how you are answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a `for` loop, which as you can imagine is problematic when trying to read from the same file you're writing to:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "val="<totalcred.txt
If %val% GEq 30000 GoTo :EOF
Set/A "val+=195"
(Echo(%val%)>totalcred.txt
```

Comment: sir I really tried but I couldn't check if the "val" variable is lesser than 30000, I only need to sum if this condition is true...

Comment: What didn't work? Are you saying that it adds 195 when %val% is more than or equal to 30000?

Comment: it don't write the new number on the file, I made a few tests and I believe that the problem is with the if statement and the sum, if you just add an "echo %val%" after (Set/A "val+=195" it still print 195 (which is the number writteon the totalcred file) and then I also removed the if statement and it also prints 195

Comment: I have changed the `if` structure to prevent the necessity for delayed expansion. This should be fine for your purposes.

Comment: it works but the problem was that when I try to get this number and use it later (my whole bat script is big) it dont returned the value in a sum like (set /a another=%val%+100), but I found the solution, if anyone else pass for this problem



 FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a IN (totalcred.txt) DO (

 set /a val=%%a + 1
 set /a val=!val!

 )

 set /a val2=%val%+100
 echo %val2%